# Samba not working through AD

Tags: debian, samba, ldap

I'm trying to get a samba to work with a windows AD. And i can't use my shares through samba.

My `smb.conf`

```
#GLOBAL PARAMETERS
[global]
   workgroup = MY_DOMAIN
   realm = MY_DOMAIN.COM
   preferred master = no
   server string = Linux Test Machine
   security = ADS
   encrypt passwords = yes
   password server = MY_MASTER_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER
   log level = 3
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m
   max log size = 50
   printcap name = cups
   printing = cups
   winbind enum users = Yes
   winbind enum groups = Yes
   winbind use default domain = Yes
   winbind nested groups = Yes
   winbind separator = +
   idmap uid = 1100-20000
   idmap gid = 1100-20000
   ;template primary group = "Domain Users"
   template shell = /bin/bash



[homes]
   comment = Home Direcotries
   valid users = %S
   read only = No
   browseable = No

[tmp]
   comment = Directory for storing pictures by jims users
   path= /var/tmp
   Valid Users = @"MY_DOMAIN+group name" MY_DOMAIN+MY_ACCOUNT
  ; public=no
   writable=yes
   browseable=yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

`wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g` work as expected. `kinit MY_ACCOUNT@MY_DOMAIN.COM` works too.

But i can't connect to samba. I'm using debian 5, samba 3.2.5 and kerberos 5. My `/var/www` is 777. Any ideas ?

UPDATE :

testparm ==>

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[tmp]"
Loaded services file OK.
'winbind separator = +' might cause problems with group membership.
Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER
```

UPDATE 2 :

I'm able to connect on linux with my AD credentials, but samba don't want to let me access to my shares with the same credentials.

Comment: have you checked `testparams` ?

Comment: Yeah. Post updated.

Comment: You cannot access [tmp] or [homes] or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it doesn't work from my windows, for an unknown reason. But it does work from a linux and from 2 another windows 7. So the conf file i gave is right.

Edit :

This is indeed an answer, because the samba/kerberos was working. The problem came from my windows, it had a wrong (old) login/pwd (linked to my linux server) saved in the secured password location. It seems windows was sending these old credentials and not the one i typed.

We got the same problem on 2 or 3 computers. Everything worked once we removed it.

Comment: This is not an answer. You can edit your question to add additional information.

Comment: is your windows machine is part of your domain ?

Comment: have you checked any errors in smb logs ?

Comment: @Marco, indeed it was an answer, at least to the samba problem. Because samba was perfectly functional. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you login, did you try with the following:

```
DOMAINAME\username
```

as your username? Also, try checking the permission settings of your /usr/tmp and your home directories.

Also, you might want to set the path to the home directories, mine is setup as such:

```
path = /home/%S
valid users = %D+%S
```

Even with "winbind use default domain = Yes", I still had to login with my domain name..

Edit: I am using Samba version 3.5.10. Not sure if it matters.